# Hide visible div on show another div in javascript php?

Tags: javascript, tags, hide, visible

I have visible div and I want to hide visible div on show another div in javascript.

my js:-

```
`function shownote(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementByClassName('comment').style.display = "hidden";
}`
```

my code:-

```
`<td>
    <?php echo $key; ?><br><input type='button' class="btn" value="Note"      onclick="shownote('comment<?php echo $unique; ?>')">
    <div class="comment" id="comment<?php echo $unique; ?>"  style="display:none;">
    <textarea id="notemenu" name="notemenu" placeholder="Note Here"></textarea>  <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"><a href>Cancel</a>
    </div> 
</td>`
```

Comment: `display='none'` also does not working

Answer (score 0):

> `hidden` is not a valid property for display. Try display='none'. Also note, `getElementsByClassName`(also correct typo here) will return `nodelist`, iterate all the nodes and set the property

```js
function shownote(id) {
  var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('comment');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(comments, function(elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  });
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: this is not working with this code shown div also hide.

Comment: It will remove all the elements having class as `comment`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByClassName('comment').style.display = "none";
```

Instead of `hidden` you have to use `none`

Comment: It has a typo in `getElementByClassName` it must be `getElementsByClassName`. `document.getElementByClassName('comment')` will return array-like nodelist not a single element like `getElementById`